# I got an console error, after logged to website in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, rxjs6

Am using rxjs 6.3.3 version it throw error on `console` after logged to webpage. I didn't get any idea to clear this error

```
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:68)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:29)
```

Comment: You need to show us a little bit of the code so we can try to see where the subscription fails

Comment: i had lot of components in src, i cant find where it fails, help me with this. Using Angular 7, rxjs version is 6.3.3

Comment: Sadly we need more information from the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to come from a Subscription from a Observable. Please consider adding your code, so we can determine this better

Comment: @SuryaBharathi
You didnt add code insteadf you just showed the error message in your edit. Please consder addingt your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

check your operator importing it should be

```
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

> ***FURTHER REFERENCE***
>
> https://brianflove.com/2018/03/21/master-rxjs-operators/
>
> If you’re
>   using RxJS v5.4.x then you will want to import using the
>   prototype-based imports:
>
> ```
> import 'rxjs/add/operators/switchMap';
> ```
>
> If you’re using RxJS v5.5.x then you will use an ES6-style import of
>   the exported function, for example:
>
> ```
> import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
> ```

Comment: Thanks, am using   "rxjs": "~6.3.3", i getting this error,
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.